# PowerBI , change order in one column in stacked chart

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am creating a Power BI  report in Stacked column chart. Can I change the order in a column, just like show in the picture?

Hope some masters can help me to solve the problem!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this is to define a custom column with values that will give you the desired sorting order, and then use [Sort by column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-sort-by-column#sort-using-the-sort-by-column-button).

Open `Power Query Editor` by clicking on `Edit Queries` button, and in `Add Column` tab click on `Custom Column`. To reverse the sort order, you can subtract `Level` from some bigger number, e.g. a million, so enter this formula:

```
Custom Sort Order = 1000000 - [Level]
```

Like this:

[image]

Close `Power Query Editor` and apply the changes, then select your stacked column chart visual and in `Fields` pane click on the `Level` column. In `Modeling` tab, click on `Sort by Column` button and from the dropdown select the newly defined custom column:

[image]

This will sort the segments in reverse order.